Codeception: Acceptance test is running as the first test in the test group, where API test is defined as the first test in the group: How to resolve?
I use Codeception framework and Netbeans IDE for my test automation using PHP.
I would like to run 2 tests one after another in a group, where the API test will run first and after the successful run of the API test, next the Acceptance test should run as the Acceptance test depends on the success of the API test.
Here is what I did to get that work:
The API test is created here in my project:
FT/tests/api/MyAPITestCest.php

The Acceptance test is created here in my project:
FT/tests/acceptance/MyAcceptanceTestCest.php

My codeception.yml file is defined here:
FT/codeception.yml

And in the codeption.yml file I defined my group which would run the api test & the acceptance test one after another.
actor: Tester
paths:
  tests: tests

groups:
  myGroup: [tests/api/MyAPITestCest.php, tests/acceptance/MyAcceptanceTestCest.php]

This is the command I used to run my group of tests:
sudo docker-compose run -e ENVVARIABLE=abc.my.env.com tests vendor/bin/codecept run -g myGroup -vvv --html results.html

Issue
Acceptance test is always running as the first test in the test group although the API test has been defined as the first one in the group
That's why Acceptance test is never getting the input which would get generated by the API test and thus it's always failing.
Not sure what is going wrong; appreciate your valuable input so that I can successfully run my API test before the Acceptance test in the same sequence defined in my test group.
Thanks in advance!

I got the solution.
This is what I did:

I needed to execute my API test before Acceptance test and use the output of that very API method in the Acceptance test.

As the solution, I called the required api test method inside acceptance test class. This is what I did for that:


2.i. In the acceptance yml file I added the API helper class (RestAPIAdminUser) as an enabled module:
modules:
    enabled:
        - \Helper\Acceptance
        - \Helper\RestAPIAdminUser

2.ii. It enabled me to create instance of this RestAPIAdmin user class inside my acceptance test class and now with the help of that instance I am now able to use my required api test method inside the acceptance test class, before the very acceptance method which would need input from this api method.
